# How do I get the number of images that a MagickWand is holding?

Tags: c, imagemagick, magickwand

I can iterate though them and count, but I don't see any methods to return the number of images directly. Is there one?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [MagickGetNumberOfImages()](http://support.cs.nott.ac.uk/help/docs/image/ImageMagick/www/api/magick_wand.html)  ( note: apparently is no longer supported in newer versions )

> ```
>     MagickGetNumberOfImages() returns the number of images associated with a 
>     magick wand. 
>
>     The format of the MagickGetNumberOfImages method is:
>
>         unsigned long MagickGetNumberOfImages ( MagickWand *wand ); 
>
>     A description of each parameter follows:
>
>     wand:
>         The magick wand.
> ```

Comment: I'd like to vote this answer down, but the system won't let me.

Comment: That function doesn't exist in MagickWand.h. And I can't find it in any official documentation. Maybe it's from  very old version?

Comment: I believe it's from one of the 5.7 versions. And I think you need more reputation points to downvote an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The incorrect answer above references an API function that's no longer in the latest version of the MagickWand API.

The best way I found to do it is:

```
MagickSetLastIterator(wand);
size_t num = MagickGetIteratorIndex(wand_);
```

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what version you are using then?

Comment: the latest binary release appears to be 6.7.9, but I'm sure you could've looked that up yourself ;)

Comment: For the "num" variable, make sure you use ssize_t (signed) and not size_t, otherwise you won't be able to check for the -1 (no images).

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of the MagickWand API (I'm using 6.8.4) they seem to have brought back this function as `MagickGetNumberImages()`

http://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php#MagickGetNumberImages